# how to retrieve integer value from database & store it in integer in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{

   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select FromYear from Factory where Cal_ID='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();
    d = dr[0].ToString();
   //d =(string) Label4.Text;
    con.Close();

  }
```

I want integer value from database

Comment: use:

`int d = dr.GetInt32[0];`

also check:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388475/reading-int-values-from-sqldatareader

Comment: If you want, then why don't you just do it: ∫i=Convert.ToInt32(dr[0];int i = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "select FromYear from Factory where Cal_ID='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
cmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dr.Read();
int d = dr.GetInt32(0);
con.Close();
```

`dr.GetInt32(0)` should read  an int at position 0

Comment: Please use the parameters (`"select FromYear from Factory where Cal_ID=@param`) avoiding string concatenation: [SqlCommand with Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{

   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   cmd.CommandText = "select FromYear from Factory where Cal_ID='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
   cmd.Connection = con;
   con.Open();

   d = GetYear(cmd).ToString();

   con.Close();
}
```

the "dirty" work is done by *GetYear* :

```
private const DEFAULT_YEAR = 2000;
private int GetYear(System.Data.IDbCommand command) {
   int year = DEFAULT_YEAR;
   using (System.Data.IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
      if (reader.Read()) {
         year = GetIntOrDefault(reader, 0);
      }
   }
   return year;
}

private  int GetIntOrDefault(System.Data.IDataRecord record, int ordinal) {
   if (record.IsDBNull(ordinal)) {
      return DEFAULT_YEAR;
   } else {
      return record.GetInt32(ordinal);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string InvAmountQuery = "SELECT InvAmount FROM Registration WHERE Email='" + useremail + "' ";
SqlCommand InvAmountcom = new SqlCommand(InvAmountQuery, conn);
int InvAmount = Convert.ToInt32(InvAmountcom.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```